# PHP preg_match doesn't match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get string from xml here:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MZoO8QVMxkk?v=2
```

I want to get video title as variable `$vtitle` and video description as `$vdescription`

```
<?php 
    $vinfo = @file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MZoO8QVMxkk?v=2");
    $vtitle = preg_match("/<media:title type='plain'>(.*?)<\/media:title>/", $vinfo, $match);
    $vtitle = $match[1];
    $vdescription = preg_match("/<media:description type='plain'>(.*?)‬‬<\/media:description>/", $vinfo, $match);
    $vdescription = $match[1]; 
?>
<h1><?php echo $vtitle; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $vdescription; ?></p>
```

Output for $vtitle:

> New Avengers Trailer Arrives - Marvel's Avengers: Age of Ultron
>   Trailer 2

Why output for $vdescription is empty or doesn't match?
Please help what's wrong with this code?
Thanks

Eva

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `s` flag or replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`

`s` flag enables dotall mode.

It would be more advisable to use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which was suggested by @Bob0t as they're more fail-proof and are specifically built for handling XMLs and HTML

Comment: dotall because between the starttag and the endtag are one or more line breaks and without dotall PCRE doesn't match linebreaks for . (dot)

Comment: @EvaSilviana Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```html
$vdescription = preg_match("/<media:description type='plain'>(.*?)‬‬<\/media:description>/si", $vinfo, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot character in your regular expression is not matching new lines, which is causing preg_match to report no matches.

[You need to add the "**s**" flag to your pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

```
    $vdescription = preg_match("/<media:description type='plain'>(.*?)‬‬<\/media:description>/s", $vinfo, $match);
```

Just to reiterate what others have said, you will have a much easier time using something like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to process XML than you will with regular expressions.